# How can I stop a worker thread in tkinter when window is closed?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

When I close the tkinter window while the worker thread is running I get this error after 10 seconds: `RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop` probably because `ROOT` is destroyed.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import time


def worker(event_ready):
    event_ready.wait()

    progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(ROOT, orient='horizontal', mode='indeterminate', length=280)
    progress_bar.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=20)

    progress_bar.start()
    time.sleep(10)
    progress_bar.stop()



event_ready = threading.Event()
worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(event_ready,))
worker_thread.start()

global ROOT
ROOT = tk.Tk()
ROOT.geometry('300x120')
ROOT.title('TEST')
ROOT.grid()
event_ready.set()
ROOT.mainloop()
```

How can stop worker thread a soon as I close window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply only need to start the Thread as a daemon, at least in Windows.

```
worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(event_ready,), daemon=True)
```

Now when you close the Window, the program will terminate immediately.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the worker thread as soon as you close the tkinter window, you can use the protocol method in the Tk class to handle the window closing event. This allows you to define a function that will be called when the window is closed.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import time

def worker(event_ready, stop_event):
    event_ready.wait()
    progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(
        ROOT,
        orient='horizontal',
        mode='indeterminate',
        length=280
    )
    progress_bar.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=20)

    progress_bar.start()
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        time.sleep(0.1)
    progress_bar.stop()
    ROOT.destroy()


def on_closing():
    stop_event.set()


event_ready = threading.Event()
stop_event = threading.Event()
worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(event_ready, stop_event), daemon=True)
worker_thread.start()

ROOT = tk.Tk()
ROOT.geometry('300x120')
ROOT.title('TEST')
ROOT.grid()
event_ready.set()

ROOT.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing) 
ROOT.mainloop()
```

The *on_closing* function is bound to the window's closing event using ROOT.protocol, and it simply sets the stop_event flag, signaling the worker thread to stop.

This way, when you close the tkinter window, the *on_closing* function will be called, stopping the worker thread, and then the window will be closed gracefully.

Comment: If I remove `daemon=True` from `threading.Thread(...)`, the program does not exit even the window is closed.

Comment: If you remove daemon=True from the threading.Thread(...), the worker thread will become a non-daemon thread, and it will prevent the program from exiting even if the tkinter window is closed. This happens because non-daemon threads are expected to complete before the program exits, so the Python interpreter will wait for non-daemon threads to finish before terminating the program.

Comment: What I mean is that what you propose does not work. It works because of setting `daemon=True`.